# How to hide pages numbers on vue-pagination-2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this code:

```
   <div id="registros-dataset" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div v-if="dataset.collectedData && dataset.collectedData.length > 0 && !isLoading">
            <maare-dataset-result-panel :dataset="dataset"></maare-dataset-result-panel>
        </div>
        <h4 v-else-if="isLoading">carregando...</h4>
        <pagination for="dataset-result-panel" 
            :records="Number(dataset.count)" 
            :per-page="resultsPerPage" 
            :limit=0
            count-text="Exibindo de {from} a {to}, total de {count}"
            class="center"
            ref="p">
        </pagination>
    </div>
```

But `vue-pagination` shows me like this:

> << < 1 2 3 ... > >>

How can I hide the pages numbers, and show only Next and Back  buttons?

Comment: I don't think a built-in option exists for this. Have you considered using CSS instead? You may need to use a few `:not` pseudo-selectors, but I'm sure you can get something working. This is probably the simplest option available to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such option (to hide page numbers) exists on [vue-pagination-2](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-pagination-2#usage).

Having a look at the [page numbers source code](https://github.com/matfish2/vue-pagination-2/blob/c095767eb51cbfb791c41e9314cf205e7822c5c7/src/template.js#L11), your best bet is really CSS, since there is a pattern:

- The page numbers always use the `VuePagination__pagination-item`
- The arrows also use `VuePagination__pagination-item`, but also use, additionally:

  - `.VuePagination__pagination-item-prev-page`
  - `.VuePagination__pagination-item-prev-chunk`
  - `.VuePagination__pagination-item-next-page`
  - `.VuePagination__pagination-item-next-chunk`

As when it comes to CSS, you have a fair amount of possible selectors (such as `li.VuePagination__pagination-item:nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(n+3) {`), but I believe the safest alternative is:

```css
li.VuePagination__pagination-item:not(.VuePagination__pagination-item-prev-page):not(.VuePagination__pagination-item-prev-chunk):not(.VuePagination__pagination-item-next-page):not(.VuePagination__pagination-item-next-chunk) {
  display: none;
}
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    Pagination
  },
  data: {
    page: 1
  },
  methods: {
    setPage: function(page) {
      this.page = page;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#app {
  text-align: center;
}

li.VuePagination__pagination-item:not(.VuePagination__pagination-item-prev-page):not(.VuePagination__pagination-item-prev-chunk):not(.VuePagination__pagination-item-next-page):not(.VuePagination__pagination-item-next-chunk) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.9/vue.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/matfish2/vue-pagination-2/master/dist/vue-pagination-2.min.js"></script>
    
<div id="app">
  <h2>Vue Pagination 2</h2>
  <p>Selected page: {{page}}</p>
  <pagination :records="10000" :per-page="100" @paginate="setPage">
  </pagination>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to hide a portion of the numbers? By default it shows 10 options. I only want 5. Taking your above answer into consideration, I added this:
 
`li.VuePagination__pagination-item:nth-child(n+8):nth-last-child(n+3) {
  display:none;
}`

And it did show me only 5 numbers but the rest are just hidden and a user can still navigate to the numbers without any display.

Comment: @AadeshDhakal I really am not aware of any way to do that. Maybe there is. I think your best bet is opening an issue in the repo: https://github.com/matfish2/vue-pagination-2/issues